# ef6 connection string cached and cannot change

Tags: c#, entity-framework

good day
I have a serious problem

I save my connection string to the registry and on runtime, I passed to the ef constructor like this

```
private static string ConnectionString()
    {
        RegistryKey GetobjRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(StaticLinks.SoftwareRegisteryPath, true);

        return (string)GetobjRegistryKey.GetValue("ConnectionString");
    }

  public BMSContext()
        : base(ConnectionString())
    {


        Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(null);

    }
```

but when I change the connection string it sticks to the old one and never changes I tried multiple solutions deleting obj folder remove entity framework restart but all of these are in vain could you help me in this problem
the weird thing is that the migrations and the update work as expect but when viewing data it views from the old database which really weird

Comment: Why would you change the connection string, while the application is running?

Comment: because when transferring the app to another location it will have another connection string setted by the user

Comment: You cannot transfer a running application. You'd start a new instance, which would read the registry value on startup again.